# Using the Loop to show all levels of subpages under a parent page? Halfway there

Tags: loop, pages

I have a need to make the Loop run through all of the children of a parent, all of the children of each child, etc. The reason I need the Loop instead of a listing tag like wp_list_pages is so that I can display any information associated with the pages using WP template tags and functions. It's for a showcase-style display that has hierarchical content and gets rearranged, so pages > posts for this usage.

I've gotten as far as getting the loop to show children of the current page and an inner loop going to show grandchildren, but this is just a brute-force prototype, and I need to take it to the next level.

What I think I need to do is use 1 loop that starts with post_parent (so that it shows child pages) but insert a function to change the post ID to each child page found so that the loop continues to drill down until it runs out, then backs out 1 level, goes to the next available ID, etc.

My problem is that I'm not enough of a WP programmer (or real programmer at all) to get that going. If it were all out in code I bet I could work it out, but WP has obviously got hidden functions going with have_post and the_post to cycle through the available post IDs, and that has me lost as to how to integrate what I need.

Here's where I am at the moment. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php   
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => '',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',);

query_posts($args); ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?>:</a>

<?php     $inner_query = new WP_Query("post_type=page&posts_per_page=-1&post_parent={$id}&order_by=title&order=ASC"); ?>

<?php while ($inner_query->have_posts()) : $inner_query->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?>:</a>

<?php endwhile; // end inner loop ?>
<?php endwhile; //end outer loop ?>     
<?php endif; // end outer if have_posts?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a recursive function, ie a function that calls itself. Here's a rough outline of how it can be done:

```
function wpse13669_show_all_children( $post_id, $current_level ) {
    $children = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' =>'page',
        'posts_per_page' =>-1,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'order_by' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC' ) );
    if ( empty($children) ) return;

    echo '<ul class="children level-'.$current_level.'-children">';

    foreach ($children as $child) {

        /* Here would be the point where you
            do whatever you want to display the 
            posts. The variable $current_level can
            be used if you want to style different 
            levels in the hierarchy differently */

            echo '<li>';

        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($child->ID).'">';
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $child->post_title );
        echo '</a>';

        // now call the same function for child of this child
        wpse13669_show_all_children( $child->ID, $current_level+1 );

            echo '</li>';

        }

    echo '</ul>';

    }
```

*Note: edited my code to show the kind of nested `<ul>` lists it sounds like you're looking for. If you want to see how WordPress does stuff like this internally (its a lot more complicated than this, but worth figuring out if you need to do anything really custom in your code), you should look through the source code for the* [class-wp-walker.php](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php.source.html) *file, where the Walker class that handles all the various nested lists (menus, comments, page lists, etc) throughout WP.*

If you define that function with the output structure you want and just call it from within your loop, it should do what you're looking for. I put a $current_level variable in there just so that you can easily style children different from grand-children, and so on.

*(within your main loop)*

```
wpse13669_show_all_children( $post->ID, 1 );
```

Comment: Now see? Unlike WP's Loop, THIS I understand! Thank you Apples!

Comment: Ok next question - how do I accept this answer / give you karma points / send you cookies?

Comment: Ha, I know what you mean. I find it much easier to use foreach statements for any secondary loops... the globals that are overridden in the standard `the_post()` loop always confuse me. There should be a checkbox next to the answer where you can accept it...

Comment: Oops, problemo! I found that even though this function is being called from within the loop, apparently standard WP tags don't work in it (i.e. the_permalink(), the_title(), comments_number(), etc.).

Comment: Re the above - I tried adding 'setup_postdata($child);' to the foreach loop but that didn't help. I fished around for hours trying to figure it out myself (tried replacing foreach with another Loop, which worked for the tags but failed to pass the post ID as needed). So I'm really stuck :( Might you have any advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: `setup_postdata()` only works with a post object called __$post__, not $child or anything else. You'd have to store a backup of the current $post variable in another variable before calling each sub-loop, then restore it after returning from that loop. Its a hassle, and that's why I typically work around it by using the alternative functions - ie `echo get_permalink($child->ID)` instead of `the_permalink()`. You might have to write a little more and your code might be slightly less readable, but it saves you from worrying about scope and globals.

Comment: well blarg. My concern was that useful plugins might involve filters on the WP tags, so I was all for maintaining compatibility. I do have a sample of a loop within a loop using a stored / restored post variable, so I will give that the old college try. If not, I still have a working method, so no harm done. Thanks much for your help!

Comment: ....double blarg. I've got list and wrapper tags inserted correctly, but I can't figure out where to get a "last_level" count from.

Comment: @goldenapples sorry for the multi-comments, but somebody in charge of this site thinks we're commenting on each other's cat pictures instead of discussing code. Re the last comment, I've got 3 of 4 list and wrapper tags inserted correctly, but I can't figure out where to get a "last_level" count from so I can determine when to insert a closing wrapper tag. Can you point the place where I can snag the current level before it's incremented for the next child loop? The next comment has the code I've got in so far, between the $children array and the if check for children.

Comment: Here's the wrapper tag code so far.  
    if($last_level > $current_level) echo "</ul>"; //check the last count against the current count. If the current count has been decremented, close the child list wrapper.
    
    $last_level = $current_level; //equalize the counts for the next loop's check - this is not in the right place.
    
    if (($children) )  { 
    echo '<ul class="children">'; //if there's children, create a child list wrapper
    } 
    else {
    echo "</li>"; // if there's no children, close the list item
    return; // if there's no children, exit this iteration
    }

Comment: Hi @dains ... will try to address your points separately. Regarding filters: you can apply the filters without using template tags. Look up the source of the template tags to see what filters each one of them applies. For example, `echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $child->post_title );` in my example above applies exactly the same filters that are applied with `the_title()` template tag.

Comment: You really shouldn't need to check the last level count to figure out whether to wrap a list with an additional `<ul>` tag. If you reach the foreach loop, you know that you're descending a level. I'll update my code with an example.

Comment: Thanks Apples! My problem is that I can't tell when it's finished a level, so that I can close the ul / li before the next iteration. Unless I'm not understanding the sequence correctly, which is completely likely :) Regarding the filters, I meant filters that might be applied to the standard template tags by a plugin, such as one to insert javascript into the link or something like. I haven't found the answer so far, so I'm just going to go with what we have and worry about compatibility later.

Comment: @goldenapples Ok your loop-fu has defeated me /kung-fu bow. Thank you so much for pushing the car all the way home, up the driveway and into the garage to boot!

Comment: @goldenapples You saved my bacon with this answer! Upvote! :)