# Display posts of custom type in hierarchical order

Tags: custom-post-types, child-pages

I has custom field 'People' and I have parent pages(post types) and child pages (post types). 
This is my code:

```
<?php 
 $args = array( 
'post_type'=> 'people',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php $loop->the_post();?>
     <div class="title">    
         <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I need display this custom post types in hierarchical order. For example:

```
First parent post type
   - first child of first parent post type
   -second child of first parent post type
Second parent post type
   -first child of second parent post type
```

But by default this posts displayed in other by time of publish.
Any ideas, how resolved this problem?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1

To loops through parent pages and child pages you need a recursive funtion. Luckily goldenapples has written one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13678/1878

## Part 2

That takes care of that but you still want to be able to order it, so WordPress allows us to set a Page Order. If you go into the edit page screen you will see under the Attributes box a spot for order. You can also set the order in the quick edit screen.
[image: Page Quick Edit Screen]

And then we need to tell the loop for orderby that order:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 
    'post_type'=> 'people',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your arguments and do

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'people',
  'title_li'=> __('People')
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

`post_type` is an acceptable argument and will take care of the recursion for you.