# Custom post type hierarchical loop in Homepage

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, hierarchical

I read this: [Display posts of custom type in hierarchical order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39212/display-posts-of-custom-type-in-hierarchical-order) But didn't understand if and how to use the answer.

This what i would like to achieve:

if_user_logged_in

show user's created cpost in hierarchical order

Is it possible to list custom posts in Homepage with this structure?

[image]

No problems in backend:

[image: No problems in backend]

Customer 1 (parent) the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()

- Item 1 belongs to Customer 1 Children of Customer 1 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()
- Item 2 belongs to Customer 1 Children of Customer 1 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()
- Item 3 belongs to Customer 1 Children of Customer 1 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()
- Item 4 belongs to Customer 1 Children of Customer 1 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()

Customer 2

- Item 1 belongs to Customer 2 Children of Customer 2 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()
- Item 2 belongs to Customer 2 Children of Customer 2 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()
- Item 3 belongs to Customer 2 Children of Customer 2 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()
- Item 4 belongs to Customer 2 Children of Customer 2 the_title() - the_permalink() - edit_post_link()

And so on, I think you have the point :)

This is how I registered my cPost:

```
/*Custom post clienti */
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cliente' );

function register_cpt_cliente() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Clienti', 'cliente' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Cliente', 'cliente' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Aggiungi nuovo', 'cliente' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Aggiungi un nuovo cliente', 'cliente' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Modifica cliente', 'cliente' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nuovo client', 'cliente' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Guarda cliente', 'cliente' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Cerca cliente', 'cliente' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Nessun cliente trovato', 'cliente' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Nessun cliente eliminato', 'cliente' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Cliente superiore:', 'cliente' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Clienti', 'cliente' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Un archivio per gestirli tutti (Cit.)',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'abruzzo', 'basilicata', 'calabria', 'campania', 'emilia-romagna', 'friulli-venezia-giulia', 'lazio', 'liguria', 'lombardia', 'marche', 'molise', 'piemonte', 'puglia', 'san_marino', 'sardegna', 'sicilia', 'toscana', 'trentino-alto_adige', 'umbria', "valle_d'aosta", 'veneto' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/cli20.png',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'cliente', $args );
}
```

This is my loop that, obviusly works but has no hierarchical structure:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {;?>
    <div id="listaclienti-container">
        <?php global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $idutente = $current_user->ID;
            $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
               'post_type' => 'cliente',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'author' => $idutente) 
            );?>

        <ul id="listaclienti">

            <?php if (have_posts()) { ?>
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
                    <li>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?><?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' | ', ''); ?>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile;
            }else{echo 'No posts here';};?>
        </ul><!-- listaclienti -->

    </div><!-- listaclienti Container -->
<?php };?><!-- end of if user_logged_in -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of your code, all you are doing is creating a nested list. If so, the easiest thing would be [`wp_list_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_members_of_a_custom_post_type).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'cliente',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'author' => $idutente, // must be comma separated list of IDs
);
wp_list_pages($args);
```

`wp_list_pages` only seems to work with `'hierarchical' => true,`, but you have registered your CPT with that argument.

You should be able to style it with CSS however you want.

If you need something more complicated, you may need a custom Walker, something like this:

```
class My_Page_Walker extends Walker_Page {
  function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $link = get_edit_post_link($page->ID);
    $link = '<a class="post-edit-link" href="' . $link . '">Edit</a>';
    $output .= ' ('.$link.') </li>';
  }
}

$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'cliente',
  'post_status'=> 'publish',
  'walker' => new My_Page_Walker
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

Comment: Do you know if it possible to add an EDIT link to each page permalink?

Something like:

Page (Edit)
 - Sub (Edit)
 - Sub2 (Edit)


This is what I've got but it echoes an EDIT link before the UL and it is related to my custom homepage.  

`<?php
wp_reset_query();    
$args = array(  
    'post_type'    => 'cliente',  
    'post_status'  => 'publish',  
 'title_li'     => __(''),  
 'link_after'   => "</a>".edit_post_link('Edit', ' | ', '')."",  
 'sort_order '  => 'DESC',  
 
 'echo' => 1,  
    'author' => $idutente, // must be comma separated list of IDs  
);  
wp_list_pages($args);?>`

Comment: This is what I actually got: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LWlYT4L.png?1)

Comment: @Downloadtaky : see the edit

Comment: Thank you once again. I'm using your walker class and I'm trying to understand why the parent EDIT is after the childs.
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/5SX9rcD.png)